# Assigning keyboard shortcut to iOS User Agent in Safari's develop menu

Tags: keyboard, safari

I am trying to assign a keyboard shortcut to the `Develop > User Agent > Safari iOS 8.1 - iPhone` menu item of Safari web browser. But in the `System Preferences > Keyboard > App Shortcuts`, when I enter `Safari iOS 8.1 - iPhone`, the keyboard shortcut does not work.

I suppose that hyphen [-] like character that appears in the user agent menu is some other character. Can somebody tell what character is that so that I can the keyboard shortcut working.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an n-dash to me, rather than a hyphen

Hyphen -

N-dash —

typing 2 hyphens will change to an n-dash in regular text areas, if you have Smart dashes enabled in Edit > Substitutions, otherwise you could try copy/pasting this one...

Safari iOS 8.1 — iPad

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Safari use the `em-dash` instead of `n-dash`.

Example:

```
Safari — iOS 9.3 — iPhone
```

You can find it under the punctuation section of the Character Picker.